# How can I transition the background WHILE dragging the sun?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a page on which you can drag an image of the sun in an arc. As you drag the sun, it transitions from a bright sun into a darker sun and then into the moon. Now I'd like the background image to transition, too.

How can I make the current sky background image gradually fade into a tiled image of the night sky (like the one below) halfway through the sun's arc?

[image]

This is the "program": http://whatisupson.tumblr.com/

```js
var width = 300,
  sun = $("#sun"),
  dark = $("#dark_sun"),
  moon = $("#moon"),
  total = $(window).width()
firstOfThree = (total / 3) * 0,
  secondOfThree = (total / 3) * 1,
  thirdOfThree = (total / 3) * 2;

sun.draggable({
  axis: "x",
  containment: 'body',
  drag: function() {
    var x = sun.offset().left + (sun.width() / 2),
      heightPct = Math.pow((total / 2) - x, 2) / Math.pow($(window).width() / 2, 2);
    this.style["margin-top"] = "" + Math.round(heightPct * 30) + "%";

    dark.css({
      left: x - (sun.width() / 2),
      marginTop: heightPct * 30 + "%"
    });

    $(this).css({
      opacity: (1 - (x / thirdOfThree)) >= 0 ? (1 - (x / thirdOfThree)) : 0,
      marginTop: heightPct * 30 + "%"
    });
    moon.css({
      left: sun.offset().left,
      marginTop: heightPct * 30 + "%"
    });

    if (x > thirdOfThree) {
      dark_opacity = 1 - ((x - thirdOfThree) / (total - x - sun.width() / 2));
      dark.css({
        opacity: dark_opacity
      });
      moon.css({
        opacity: 1
      });
    } else {
      moon.css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      dark.css({
        opacity: 1
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/aZty7Mq.png);
  animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: mymove 4s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 40% 0;
  }
}
#moon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
}
#dark_sun {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
}
#sun {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<img id="moon" src="http://i.imgur.com/VmFEwrH.png">
<img id="dark_sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/f3UFHb7.png">
<img id="sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/DGkZYZQ.png">
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: You can improve this :) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVvZpr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use fixed layers and transition the opacity of the fixed layers.

The `getOpacity` function accepts two parameters, *Z* (percentage) and the index of the div and uses those (along with the number of elements) to calculate opacity while assuring each `.bg` is fully visible at some point during the drag. It sets and returns the values in the cos function.

```
opacity = A*Math.cos(P*0 + Z*Math.PI - (index*Math.PI)/L) + V
```

I made a visualization [created a visualization @desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nqbzzs8mwb) and added a snippet to make it easy for everyone to understand how it works.

```js
$(function(){

    var bg = $(".bg"),
        drag = $(".drag"),
        sun = $("#sun"),
        csel = '#container'; // container selector

    _init();

    // hoistorzs

    function _init(){
        onDrag();
        sun.css({
            opacity:1
          })
          .draggable({
            axis: "x",
            containment: csel,
            drag:onDrag
        });
    }
  
    function getOpacity(Z,index){
        Z = 1 - Math.min(Math.max(0,Z),1); // guarantee 0 < x < 1
        var len = bg.length;
        var A = 1,
            P = 1,
            V = -A + 1,
            x = 0, // we need y at x=zero
            L = len - 1, // resolves fencepost error calculating arc indices
            opacity = A*Math.cos(P*0 + Z*Math.PI - (index*Math.PI)/L) + V; // 0-1;
        return opacity;
    }

    function onDrag(){
        var len = bg.length,
            total = $(csel).width(),
            min=sun.width()/2+8,
            max=total-min,
            x = sun.offset().left + (min),
            p = (x-min)/(max-min),
            w = sun.width(),
            heightPct = Math.pow((total >> 1) - x, 2) / Math.pow(total >> 1, 2),
            rounded = Math.round(heightPct * 30) + "%";

        bg.each(function(i){
            var op = getOpacity(p,i);
            $(this).css({
                opacity:op
            });
        });
      
        drag.each(function(i){
            var op = getOpacity(p,i);
            $(this).css({
                opacity:op > .5 ? 1 : 0,
                left: sun.css("left"),
                top: sun.css("top"),
                marginTop: rounded
            });
          
        })
    }
})
```

```css
#container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;  
}
img.drag {
  position: absolute;
  opacity:-1;
  height:30%;
  bottom:10%;
  transition:opacity 1s;
}
div.bg {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  animation: mymove 40s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes mymove {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to { background-position: 300px 0; }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!-- ADD AS MANY IMAGE AS YOU LIKE HERE IN REVERSE ORDER -->
  
  <!-- NIGHT -->
  <div class="bg" id="night" style="background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/JK3hIxi.gif);"></div>
  <img class="drag" id="moon" src="http://i.imgur.com/VmFEwrH.png">

  <!-- EVENING -->
  <div class="bg" id="evening" style="background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/9UqDlgv.png)"></div>
  <img class="drag" id="dark_sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/f3UFHb7.png">
  
  <!-- DAY -->
  <div class="bg" id="day" style="background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/aZty7Mq.png)"></div>
  <img class="drag" id="sun" src="http://i.imgur.com/DGkZYZQ.png">  

</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! But how come the day sky doesn't become fully opaque at the very end of the arc? And how do I fix it?

Comment: x is actually the sun position, so you have to subtract it's width from the screen width. I fixed it in the code snippet.

Comment: Okay thanks again! Also say that I wanted to add ANOTHER background. For example, the sunset or something. Would I just use this same procedure?

Comment: in theory we can add as many as we like and figure out the opacity using sin, offset to begin at Pi/2 and incremented by the suns position + the index of the element over the number of elements. it seems to work well after i updated the snippet.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is a tutorial for this too?

Comment: Looks like this is a pretty common demo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926245/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-drag-an-element-in-an-arc Im not sure where it came from(maybe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191236/how-do-i-make-the-arc-of-the-sun-stop-at-the-left-end-of-the-page) There is a bunch of stuff that's happening here so you'd have to be more specific about what part of it you want to learn.

Comment: fwiw, it looks like you are learning by doing on SO. Keep going, hopefully you are learning from the answers

Comment: So I tried the updated snippet, and I can't seem to get the "evening" image fully visible. There is SOME purple shown, but that is faded into the "day" image, so I can't see it very well. How can I make it, so it is FULLY visible and fully opaque when it is transitioning to the "night" image?

Comment: That didn't work either. As you can see, in your snippet as well, there are still stars showing through the "evening" image which means it never gets fully opaque. I want the same thing that happened with the "day" and "night" image to happen with the "evening" image as well. The only difference is "evening" should be in the middle.

Comment: It looks like we are running out of comments allowed in the thread so check this out: I created a visualization that should better explain how the opacity calculation is meant to work. I also improved the formula and I'll update the Answer when I get a chance. Read the comments on the left, then hit play button on the Z variable to watch the demo. Gotta run for now. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iyktryotyp

Comment: updated the code with the formula from and a link to the visualization

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot, thank you!! This is my final product: http://dayandnightsite.tumblr.com/